# Why past tense in CommandBinding.Executed

Tags: wpf

Why is it named Execute**d** and not Execute as in ICommand?

It does not matter in the end but I would expect that not to be arbitrary.

Comment: It's a notification, not a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an event that fires when the command has been... well, *Executed*, 
unlike on `ICommand`, where it's a method that *Executes* the command action when invoked.

The common norm for .NET is that events use the participle (not the past tense, mind you), and methods use the imperative.

If you want to close a Window, you call `Window.Close()`. If you want to handle to an event that rises when the window closes (or, to put it in the context of this question: "*has been **closed***"), you subscribe to `Window.Closed`.

Likewise (specifically for your question), if you want to execute a command, you call `Command.Execute`, while if you want to take some actions whenever the command has been executed (on a specific binding), you subscribe to `CommandBinding.Executed`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry for the "paste tense". I'm not native English speaking. I wondered because in the Command.Binding I thought I implement the logic that implements the command.